# How to achieve covariant parameter types in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, polymorphism, overriding, pure-virtual

I'm trying to write a matrix class interface, and then create specific implementations for each kind of matrix (e.g. row-major, col-major, sparse version etc), the problem is that the interface defines the math operations using the IMatrix class, but if i use the derived classes instead in the overriden methods it just fails to compile (since i guess in C++ covariant types only work for return types right ?).

```cpp
class IMatrix
{
    int rows, cols, count;
public:
    virtual ~IMatrix() = 0;
    virtual IMatrix& plus(IMatrix& matrix) = 0;
};

class RMMatrix: public IMatrix // row-major matrix implementation
{
    long double* data;
public:
    ~IMatrix() { delete[] data };
    RMMatrix& plus(IMatrix& matrix) override // this works but then i cannot access matrix.data
    {
        // do addition
    }
};
```

So basically I'd like to be able to override using this function signature:

```cpp
RMMatrix& plus(RMMatrix& matrix) override // fails because function signature differs from IMatrix
```

As i've said before, i'm new to OOP C++ and i can't seem to figure out the right way to enforce implementation classes (e.g. RMMatrix and other derived classes) to define these methods without using a pure virtual in the interface and without dynamic_cast =o
I thought about using templates, and giving the derived implementation class as an argument but that feels weird =s

Comment: Alas OOP doesn't have a solution for this problem. You may want to try other programming paradigms.

Comment: Damn, so my only option is to litterally remember myself to code all the methods for each implementation and hoping i don't forget or change a signature myself ? =s What other paradigms could help in this specific case scenario if i may ask ?

Comment: "remember myself to code all the methods for each implementation" If it's essentially the same method, you don't need to code it twice (templates exist). If they are different methods, well, someone have to write all the implementations down. Perhaps study other matrix libraries out there? Eigen is a widely used one.

Comment: Actually I lied a bit, you can do this with OOP, not quite but kinda sorta. All Matrix subclasses need to know about each other (which is IMHO against the spirit of OOP, but spirit is a poorly defined thing) and you will need to write separate O(N^2) versions of each operation (row-major vs column-major, row-major vs sprase etc).  Look up "double dispatch" and "visitor pattern".

Comment: Ah i know about the visitor design pattern and double dispatch, it just feels like it adds so much boilerplate code and I don't want to forsake performance =s.. I guess what you said made sense though because if the code is the same i could just use a template, however each implementation is different due to the way the data is stored in memory so i'll guess I'll just look up other libraries like you said to see how they've done it

Comment: Is there no way to use an interface as only a tag so that i can drop-in any of my matrix implementations without affecting the rest of the code (that doesn't really care about how the matrix is created/used) ?

Comment: If you only want to have one matrix implementation for your entire program, then OOP cannot guarantee you that out of the box, you have to resort to casts to ensure both operands are from the same implementation. An alternative is to make it generic (templates) but then all user code that works with matrices needs to be a template.

Comment: Ahh i read about Eigen and they seem to use "expression template metaprogramming" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_metaprogramming), so basically i think that's what you're referring to =o I guess i'll have to spend more time designing the code again before continuing

Comment: Expression templates are an optimisation technique, you don't actually have to use them...

Comment: Sorry i'm still new to all this, i just took for granted that java has covariant return and parameter types =v but is so slow in comparison; and for template metaprogramming i read that it unrolls loops at compile-time, so with that optimisation, compiling requires more time (because it's inlining the templates) but execution is sped up right (if i understood well) ?

Comment: Yes this is correct. Java's covariant *parameter* types are a hack, they are doing checks at run time. Covariant return types are OK, they exist in C++.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, so i'm just posting it here to make sure if this is a valid answer (for others to review) based on `@n.'pronouns'm`'s feedback.

```cpp
template<class Derived>
class Matrix
{
    int rows, cols, count;
public:
    virtual Derived& plus(Derived& matrix) = 0;
};


class RMMatrix: public Matrix<RMMatrix>
{
    long double* data;
public:
    ~RMMatrix() { delete[] data; };
    RMMatrix& plus(RMMatrix& matrix) override 
    { 
        // do something
    }

};
```

Edit: As stated in the comment, since Matrix is not an abstract class i can just remove the destructor and it compiles correctly

Comment: You don't need virtual anything if you use CRTP.  A virtual dtor needs to be defined even if it is pure, but you don't need it at all. `Matrix` is not really an abstract class, it's a mix-in.

Comment: Yeah that's exactly what i was reading about =O the CRTP pattern but there's still quite a few pitfalls or problems, i guess i'll just fix this code then and make another question if i have to.
Btw you replied to 3 of my SO questions in the past week, so thanks already for your time and help!